# $.post callback return strange data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I think this might be the cause of why my code is not working.. The 'if(name.val().length > 3)' is never can execute so I put an alert to test the returned data, this is what it look like :

[image]

my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var form = $("#customForm");
    var name = $("#name");
    var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
    var email = $("#email");
    var emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");
    var pass1 = $("#pass1");
    var passInfo = $("#pass1Info");
    var pass2 = $("#pass2");
    var pass2Info = $("#pass2Info");
    var state = false;

name.keyup(validateName);

function validateName(){
    if(name.val().length <= 3){
        name.removeClass("valid");
        nameInfo.removeClass("valid");
        name.addClass("error");
        nameInfo.addClass("error");
        nameInfo.text("Minimum 4 characters!");
        state = false;

    }else{

        if(name.val().length > 3){
        var username=name.val();
            $.post('validate.php',{names: username},function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(data!=0){
                    name.removeClass("valid");
                    nameInfo.removeClass("valid");
                    name.addClass("error");
                    nameInfo.addClass("error");
                    nameInfo.text("The username is already taken!");
                    state = false;
                }else{
                    name.removeClass("error");
                    nameInfo.removeClass("error");
                    name.addClass("valid");
                    nameInfo.addClass("valid");
                    nameInfo.text("username available");
                    state = true;
                }
            });

        }
    }    
}
return state;

//end
});
```

my PHP code :

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['names'];
$email = $_POST['emails'];

if($name !=""){
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Fail to connect to database");
    mysql_select_db("reglog");

    $uname = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$name'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($uname);

    if($count !=0){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
}

if($email !=""){
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Fail to connect to database");
    mysql_select_db("reglog");

    $useremail = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $countemail = mysql_num_rows($useremail);

    if($countemail !=0){
        echo 1; 
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: can you be more specific on PHP code put the filename and can you include also your form? I wanna answer that you might have a problem in your ajax data and so on..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G9VL6Fs6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is throwing an `warning`. Make a habit of checking if a `index` is available in an array, thus removing possibilities of such error.

```
$email = isset($_POST['emails']) ? $_POST['emails'] : '';
```

or do not display any errors to suppress such warning (*not recommended*).

And as mentioned by Kai, you haven't passed any variables as `emails`.

```
$.post('validate.php',{ names: username, 'emails' : email }, ... }
```

Comment: I don't think the email matter, because I followed the tutorial, the author need no to pass the email to test the username field

Comment: $email = isset($_POST['emails']) ? $_POST['emails'] : '';
this work! thx

can u explain more for this? I want to know why this error happen

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing emails as a post variable.

```
$.post('validate.php',{names: username},function(data){
```

should be

```
$.post('validate.php',{names: username, emails: email},function(data){
```

AS starx says, you should check post values with isset before running processes on the variables

Comment: We referenced each other together :)

Comment: heh, well I'll prop you cause you were first

Answer (score 0):

Make return type to `html` and it will work.

Comment: that does not change the fact that he is getting an undefined index error in php